# Using JPen in a Bamboo Pen Tablet

Tags: java, tablet, wacom

I'm doing a project on signature forgery detection and so, I need to capture signatures on a pen tablet. But I need to find a pen tablet on which I would be able to use [JPen](http://jpen.wiki.sourceforge.net/) (Java Pen Tablet Library). I intend to buy wacom's bamboo pen tablet. Does JPen work on bamboo-pen? If not, which other tablet could I use?

I read on SourceForge.net that JPen has been tested on Graphire4, Intuos2 and Intuos3. But AFAIK these models are not available in the market today. So what do I do?

Comment: Nowadays OSes have pen tablet support. I hope JPen just uses those which would mean it works with any tablet you can find drivers for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works (you probably know by now, but just in case someone comes here looking for the answer).